# How can I skip a dot in a string, if the dot comes first?

Tags: python

OK, so I got this problem from Udemy:

Create a program that takes an IP adress entered at the keyboard and prints out the number of segments it contains, and the length of each segment.

This code works perfectly fine, the only problem is when I enter an IP adress starting with a "." (yes, it's a invalid IP adress), it counts that first dot as a segment with 0 characters

### This is the program:

```py
IP = input("Insert your IP number: ")

segment = 1 
segLength = 0 
character = ""

for character in IP:
   if character == '.':
       print("segment {} contains {} characters".format(segment, segLength))
       segment += 1
       segLength = 0
    else:
        segLength += 1 if character != '.':
if character != ".":
    print("segment {} contains {} characters".format(segment, segLength))
```

## Result1 (if for example I enter 192.168.0.1):

```
segment 1 contains 3 characters
segment 2 contains 3 characters
segment 3 contains 1 characters
segment 4 contains 1 characters
```

### Result2 (if IP = .192.168.0.1)

```
segment 1 contains 0 characters  ( <-------- how do I remove this?)
segment 2 contains 3 characters
segment 3 contains 3 characters
segment 4 contains 1 characters
segment 5 contains 1 characters
```

Now, how do I make the program to skip once if IP[0] == "."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strip()` to remove the `.` when you first read the IP address.

```py
IP = input("Insert your IP number").strip('.')
```

This will remove all leading and trailing `.`:

```
192.168.0.1   => 192.168.0.1
.192.168.0.1  => 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1.  => 192.168.0.1
..192.168.0.1 => 192.168.0.1
.192.168.0.1. => 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried something weird like adding: if IP[0] or IP[-1] == ".": continue   in the for loop but that only complicated things. Your solution is the best!